# Complexity of PriorityQueue addAll()

Tags: java, data-structures, heap, big-o, priority-queue

What is the complexity of the addAll method of PriorityQueue. Does it add one element at a time resulting in O(n log n) or does it use a build heap process that creates a heap out of unordered elements in O(n) time?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) seems to imply that **`addAll` is inherited from [AbstractQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractQueue.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29)** where it is **implemented as a sequence of adds**.

This leads me to believe that the **complexity is `O(mlogn)`** where m is the size of the collection being inserted.

Comment: ...?  _O(m log n)_, not _O(m n log n)_.

Comment: I think it would be `O(m log(n+m))`. Think about case when `n=0`

Answer (score 3):

From [Priority Queue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html)

> ... this implementation provides O(log(n)) time for the enqueing and dequeing methods ...

So you can only assume `n log(n)`.

However - obviously - this is only what you can assume. Depending on the specific implementation you plan to use you may find some tricks that could improve matters for you.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the OpenJDK, it looks like PriorityQueue inherits the addAll implementation from AbstractQueue which iterates over the collection and calls add on each element.

[Source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/PriorityQueue.java)

Answer (score 0):

The `addAll` method in PriorityQueue implements `add` method for every element.
Hence it has the time complexity of `nlogn`.

But this doesn't mean there is nothing equivalent to python's heapq.heapify() or C++ make_heap method that run in O(n) complexity.
The PriorityQueue has the constructor that does the heapify operation with O(n) complexity.

```
List<Integer> x = Arrays.asList(1, 54, 22, 87, 242, 32, 11, 90);
PriorityQueue<Integer> pq1 = new PriorityQueue<Integer>(x); // O(n) complexity

PriorityQueue<Integer> pq2 = new PriorityQueue<Integer>();
pq2.addAll(x); // nlogn complexity
```

Comment: That is true, but then it uses natural ordering (so min heap for Ints). Is there a way to run heapify with a custom comparator?